# VBA Excel - ".Find" Search from top to bottom in order for column K

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to search for a specific value in column "K" and to return a specific result. But an obstacle I'm facing is that it is not going in order from top to bottom when searching the column but rather just executing "find" for "add" even though there is "term" before it. Is there a way to make it read in order cell by cell for the column?

```
Sub Find_Stuff()

Dim s As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lReply As Long
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim rngOriginal As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim n As Long


Set Cell = Columns("K:K").Find(What:="Add", LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
firstaddress = Cell.Address
Cell.Offset(0, -9).Resize(, 4).Insert shift:=xlDown
Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "add "
n = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("K9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K9:K" & n), Type:=xlFillDefault
Cell.Select
Else
        Set Cell = Columns("K:K").Find(What:="Term", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = Cell.Address
        Cell.Offset(0, -4).Resize(, 4).Insert shift:=xlDown
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "term "
        n = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("K9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K9:K" & n), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Cell.Select
        Else
                Set Cell = Columns("K:K").Find(What:="Remove", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
                firstaddress = Cell.Address
                Cell.Offset(0, -4).Resize(, 4).Insert shift:=xlDown
                Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Remove"
                n = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Range("K9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K9:K" & n), Type:=xlFillDefault
                Cell.Select
                Else
                        Columns("K:K").Select
                        Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:="New", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                        If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
                        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                        "New"
                        Cell.Select

                        End If
                        On Error GoTo 0
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*But an obstacle I'm facing is that it is not going in order from top to bottom when searching the column but rather just executing "find" for "add" even though there is "term" before it. Is there a way to make it read in order cell by cell for the column?*

This is the standard behaviour of `.Find()`. This is the description of the  `After` parameter in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel):

> The cell after which you want the search to begin. This corresponds to the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user interface. Notice that After must be a single cell in the range. Remember that the search begins after this cell; the specified cell isn't searched until the method wraps back around to this cell. If you do no specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range.

To make sure that the `.Find()` starts searching from the first cell, you have to pass as a parameter the last cell:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim myR     As Range
    Dim myS     As Range: Set myS = Range("B1:B5") 

    With myS
        Set myR = .Find(1)
        Debug.Print myR.Row
        Set myR = .Find(1, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count))
        Debug.Print myR.Row
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll make sure to look at it.